# Java String.format parametr reuse

Tags: java, format

I am new to java ,but I do have some experience in C# and I wonder how can I reuse parameters after the formatting string in String.format method. Or do I have to type them every time ?

```
String.format("first parameter: %s /*(First one again Here should be the first parameter again)*/ ",a);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

> - The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:
>
>   ```
>       %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
>   ```

`System.out.println(String.format("first parameter: %1$s %1$s","qm" ));`

Comment: `System.out.printf("first parameter: %s %<s", "qm")` would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: @VGR, I was about to mention virtually the same thing then noticed your comment. Thank you for pointing this out, I feel the it's fairly important information.

Comment: The optional argument_index is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by "1$", the second by "2$", etc.

String txt =
        String.format("Test %1$s for arg sub, Really %2$s and %1$s ok.", "foo", "bar");
   
 assertEquals("Test foo for arg sub, Really bar and foo ok.", txt);

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Test
  public void testVariableSubstitution() {
    String txt =
        String.format("Test %1$s for arg substitution, Really %2$s and %1$s ok.", "foo", "bar");
    assertEquals("Test foo for arg substitution, Really bar and foo ok.", txt);
  }
```

The optional argument_index is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by "1$", the second by "2$", etc.